# Append one list to another list

Tags: python

I have listA and listB. I want to be able to append listB to listA.

I am having some issues using the `extend` keyword. I am not sure if I am using it the right way.

```
listA = ['1.2.4.4.5']
listB = ["this is the first", "this is the second"]
```

I want to be able to have the following output:

```
res = [1.2.4.4.5.["this is the first", "this is the second"]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you are looking for append: `listA.append(listB)`?

Comment: @DanielMesejo  I tried that, but it doesnt seem to work. :( Any sample code would help

Comment: What exactly do you want in res? A list with a single string?

Comment: @LauraSmith What error and/or output do you get?

Comment: I want something like the ```res```. The listA string has the listB appended to it.

Comment: That output isn't a valid list

Comment: Im confused by your desired output - is it supposed to be `["1.2.4.4.5.["this is the first", "this is the second"]"]` or `["1.2.4.4.5", ["this is the first", "this is the second"]]`  or `["1.2.4.4.5", "this is the first", "this is the second"]`?

Comment: `listA.extend(listB)`?

Comment: `listA[-1] = listA[-1] + str(listB)` ?

Comment: @Quinn ["1.2.4.4.5.["this is the first", "this is the second"]"] is what i want

Comment: Look at my last comment it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very confusing output but here you go

```
listA[0] +"."+ str(listB)
```

OUTPUT:

```
 "1.2.4.4.5.['this is the first', 'this is the second']"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listA.extend(listB)
```

extends the listA, it does not return a result

so if you want them merged, just use the

```
listA.extend(listB)
```

and then

```
res = listA
```

Comment: Changes listA, OP didn't ask for that.

Comment: "I want to be able to append listB to listA", that's from OP's question.  I guess changing listA isn't a problem

Comment: I see no basis for this assumption in OP's question.